# Why does this jQuery.ajax not raise an error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

We had an interesting issue this morning - the details of the issue itself aren't relevant here, and I already fixed it, but I did run into something strange, to me, about jQuery.

The site I am building internally runs on https, only, so Apache is set to redirect any inbound http request to its https equivalent. This redirect is working fine. But, I had a bug in my software where I was trying to send the following ajax request:

```
jQuery.ajax({  type:       "PUT",
           url:        "http://somewhere.com/cmdt/todo_lists/8457/toggle",
           data:       { deployment_id: 827},
           dataType:   "script"});
```

I understand that this would fail - I'm alright with jQuery not wanting to follow a redirect. But the actual behaviour is even weirder: I never see an xhr request go out at all! And there's no javascript error! It just fails, silently. If I change the url to https, or to a relative path, it works fine, no problem. My question is, why wasn't it TRYING to send out the request before? And why didn't it raise an error?

Comment: This is probably the Single Origin Policy kicking in, and failing silently. You should get an error in a browser like Chrome though

Comment: This is not jQuery not _wanting_ to follow a redirect, this is cross-domain policies at work: you **cannot** request (with Ajax) a `https` resource from a `http` page, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're not getting a failure is because it's a cross-site request, and so instead of using `XMLHttpRequest`, it's actually generating an HTML `<script>` tag and dropping it into the DOM, and using that mechanism to load the file.

This works reasonably well (considering it's a complete hack around wrong-headed browser "security" notions) but there's no way for jQuery to trap errors at that point, sadly. You will likely get a browser error if you have developer mode turned on, but that's it.

Comment: Are you sure it will use a script tag if it detects that it's cross-domain?  This seems odd, I would think it would just try to send it and let the browser reject it.  I believe jsonp works how you described but I didn't think it would automatically do the same for a cross-domain non-jsonp request.

Comment: @kingjiv: I'm pretty sure for `script`, jQuery spares the developer the pain and detects. For `json`/`jsonp` you have to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you run that from an url that's `https` and try to open the equivalent `http` page you run into cross domain problems due to the different *protocols* they use. Have a look at [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).